# Propositional logic: Statement simplification to contain only a single logical operator

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Here's the logical statement: $¬[¬(A∧B)∨(¬A∧C)]∧(A∨B)$.

The answer should be $A∧B$, but i can't see how we get to remove C.

How do we get to the point where we get to use this absorption law: $p∧(p∨q) ≡ p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\overline{\overline{A \cdot B} + (\overline A \cdot C)} + A\cdot B$$
$$= \overline{\overline A + \overline B + (\overline A \cdot C)} + A\cdot B$$
$$= \overline{\overline A + \overline B } + A\cdot B$$
$$= A \cdot B + A\cdot B$$
$$= A \cdot B$$

Step 2 $\rightarrow$ 3 uses the formula you mentioned to absorb C

Comment: Oh, this depiction really helps in clarifying. Thanks for your time!